# Activity com bug que está quebrando o layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Tem uma Activity que dá um bug de vez em quando, ela fica com a aparencia da imagem que postei, aí quando clico nela, ela volta ao normal, mas isso é aleatório, tem hora que não acontece.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10sp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:text="@string/erro"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="@string/descricaoR"
    android:id="@+id/textView11" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:lines="6"
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/txtDescricaoR" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEnviar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/enviar" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLimpar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/limpar" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

O que pode ser?

Agradeço.

Comment: Já testou em um dispositivo diferente? Talvez o problema seja no dispositivo. Visualmente, o código do layout me parece ok.

Comment: Acho que o `LinearLayout` mais externo está faltando ser fechado...

Comment: Engraçado. De fato,como o @mutlei disse no comentário acima, o `LinearLayout` mais externo está aberto. Não sei como você conseguiu mandar isso para o dispositivo.

Comment: Houve algum erro na hora de entrar com o código no site, mas o LinearLayout está fechado corretamente no meu código.